# How to run Cron Job to creates files as User file instead of root file

Tags: linux, cron, devops, cron-task

Why the output file from this is owned by `root` and not `w3svcsadm`?

```
sudo -u w3svcsadm echo "TEST ran" > /home/your/emaildigest/TEST_$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S ).output
```

I'm running into some issues with **cron**, and I believe this is the key to my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using the -u flag with sudo executes the command 'echo "TEST ran"' as the user w3svcasadm, but that command isn't the thing doing the work of outputting to a file, which is done by the '>' operator. By the time bash is using that operator, it's already switched back to the user running the shell. If that user is root, then the file will be created under root. In your script, you could use "su w3svcsadm" to switch the shell user before executing that command, then you wouldn't have to use that -u flag at all.